# Pimcore Webdav not letting me login

Tags: pimcore

In the Assets Config I configured "webdav.sub.domain.TLD"

When I go on it and try to login with my Admin User I just get asked to login 
again.

When I press Cancel I get Authentication required

on WinSCP i get Access Denied.

Comment: Did you follow steps presented in https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE3/Setting+up+WebDav and https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE3/Working+with+WebDAV ?

Comment: @kubaplas yes and as admin user u already have all permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to fix this problem

It happens because im using FastCGI and its not working with HTTP AUTH

to get it to work i added a new line in my .htaccess:

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]